# group by in query join got error like SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sum

I have query join like this:

```
SELECT tb_perolehan_kaleng.id_kaleng, tb_perolehan_kaleng.perolehan_kaleng_id, tb_perolehan_kaleng.perolehan_kaleng_bulan, tb_perolehan_kaleng.perolehan_kaleng_tahun, SUM(tb_perolehan_kaleng.perolehan_kaleng_jumlah) AS total , tb_desa.*
                                FROM tb_perolehan_kaleng
                                    JOIN tb_desa 
                                        ON tb_perolehan_kaleng.id_desa=tb_desa.desa_id
                                    WHERE tb_perolehan_kaleng.perolehan_kaleng_tahun ='$tahun' AND tb_perolehan_kaleng.perolehan_kaleng_bulan='$bulan'
                                        GROUP BY tb_perolehan_kaleng.perolehan_kaleng_id
```

And I got result like this:
[image]

I want to sum this value, because the id_desa is the same. That is 6 (image in below this):
[image]

If I try like:
GROUP BY tb_perolehan_kaleng.id_desa
I got error like.... (Image in below this):
[image]

This is my first table:
[image]

In the second table, I just use that to get desa.name

What should I do to get result image 2 (image with red line)?

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand?  It seems really clear to me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry but i am new in programming sir. i just want to try to get result like image with that red line. can you help me sir ?

Comment: When there's aggregation you can use only columns found in GROUP BY or aggregated columns: Add the first 4 columns to GROUP BY, keep the SUM and remove the `, tb_desa.*`.

Comment: A quick internet search would've told you the answer. I'm not trying to be pedantic, but this is one of the most often asked questions about sql.